# What is Nolan in Icons8?

Tags: interface-design, design-principles

I found this to be interesting [Icons8 - Nolan](https://icons8.com/icon/new-icons/nolan)

Is it any new design principle? Is there any website that is based on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I like the idea about Nolan Arenado, this name is totally random.

Although it’s not based on any existing design system; Icons8 created it.

Source: I work for Icons8.

Comment: So cool! Can you also show some real life applications where Nolan is used a lot?

Answer (score 2):

A guess: There's a guy named Nolan Arenado who plays baseball in Colorado Rockies. Many posters of mr. Arenado and his team carry  the same color that is used at the end of the gradient in those icons. It's used also in CR's web page.

Those icons have the coloring and strong outline as the common factor, otherwise they seem to be anything.